# how to convert a bigQuery array row into a column and then count

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table like as shown below

[sample table AS-IS]

[image]

As shown, I would like to count each value in the "Value" column based on the ID.

as shown in the example below

[sample table TO-BE]

[image]

The data in the "Value" column is subject to change.

Can you help?

Comment: Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5211833)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider below *PIVOT* and a dynamic SQL.

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE sample_table AS
SELECT '111' ID, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] Value UNION ALL
SELECT '222', ['E', 'F', 'G'] UNION ALL
SELECT '222', ['A', 'H', 'D'];

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ID, v FROM sample_table, UNNEST(Value) v
) PIVOT (COUNT(v) FOR Value IN ('%s'))
""", (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT v, "','" FROM (SELECT ID, v FROM sample_table, UNNEST(Value) v)));
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answering,
this answer is really help for me!
[  i read your comment, also so much thank you for that :) ]